# How can I write test cases in Jest for components wrapped in withRouter()?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, enzyme

I have a stateful component called LocationFilter. I've done multiple black-box tests to ensure that this component is working properly. This is how I mount the component using Enzyme:

```
const wrapper = mount(
  <LocationFilter
    location={location}
    sendLocationFilter={jest.fn()}
    router={router}
  />
);
```

However, the state and props are undefined. This is the output showing the props as undefined when I print out wrapper.debug() in the console:

```
<withRouter(LocationFilter) location={{...}} sendLocationFilter={[Function]} router={{...}}>
  <LocationFilter location={[undefined]} sendLocationFilter={[Function]} router={{...}} params={[undefined]} routes={[undefined]}>
    <div className="FiltersSection__location">
      ...
    </div>
  </LocationFilter>
</withRouter(LocationFilter)>
```

Comment: tests are already made with withRouter https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/__tests__/withRouter-test.js, why testing it again?

Comment: @ReiDien Because the LocationFilter component itself needs to be tested. Code coverage needs to be above 80% for all the components that we make for the project.

Comment: i dont think we are on the same page here. if you want to test component away from redux see their documentation. i say redux because you are doing the same as connect.